# Two different types of character " ^ "

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, character-set

I use mathway.com for solving math-problems. So now I have a problem with typing in numbers to power like "5²" just with my keyboard. The website doesn't recognize the key-entry for the ^-character.

I use the german keyboard-layout on Ubuntu 22.04, where the ^-character is on the left side of key number 1, above "Tab". If I change the layout to USA-layout it just works fine with shift+6 !

So I changed to british layout, where there are two different types of this character ! A bigger one at shift+6 and a smaller one at AltGr + ' . The big one works as well, while the smaller one does not.
The difference between them is, that the small one is used before several letters to write special characters like: ^+e -> ê, or to write exponents high, like: 5², while the big ^-character just stays at 5^2.

What can I do ?

Thanks for help!

Comment: With the German layout, how about pressing the key twice?

Comment: Nothing happens..

Answer (score 1):

You discovered that the website does not recognize the entry when you press a dead key, i.e., the key-above-tab on your German layout. That is a problem with the website, not Ubuntu.

You will need a workaround. Two possibilities are:

- Install a US (or British) keyboard layout, and switch to it (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to enter code in the website. When done, switch back to your German layout with the same shortcut key.
- Type the code in a text editor then paste it in the website.

Comment: Yes, right know im typing formulas in the URL-box and paste them into the oage, just as you say.. I was just hoping that there would be any possibility to edit the german keyboard, so that the character moves to another key or so ?
I was browsing several forum about that and there are lots of posts about installing or custom made keyboards, but I found nothing about editing an existing one..
Thanks for your answer anyway !

Comment: The keyboard layout can be edited, but it is quite complicated. Also you could bind a shortcut to a tool like xdotool or ydotool to simulate typing the ^ character, but that has its quirks.